# adding duplicacy when checkmarks uncheck in another table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have 2 tableview in two different view where I fetch contacts using addressbook in 1st one,works fine Now I have updates to checkmarks the contact to show only check contact in another second tableview and when uncheck from 1st contact table view then it should remove from second table view ,but from below code when I uncheck from 1st table view it adds up that cell value and removes first Index value.But over here I just want to remove uncheck cell value from second table view controller.

Thanks in Advance.

**1st table view code**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";
        UITableViewCell *aCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (aCell == nil) {
            aCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        }

         aCell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] ;





        if([tableData containsObject:indexPath])
        { aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else
        { aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; }


        return aCell;
    }



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

  //  NSString *stringg = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *stringg = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
       // NSLog(@"Index path:- %@",indexPath);
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
               }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [_cat removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [_cat addObject:stringg];

    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_cat];

    NSLog(@"data save %@",dataSave);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"stringname"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

***2nd table view code from another view***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    catagory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    //category

    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringname"];
    catagory = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    _tabelViewInView.delegate = self;
    _tabelViewInView.dataSource = self;
    [_tabelViewInView reloadData];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier1 = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier1];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier1];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [catagory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *stringname1 = [catagory objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] ;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:stringname1 forKey:@"stringname1"];
    [defaults synchronize];

        ContactViewController *contact = [[ContactViewController alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:contact animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: After you add or remove data to categoryTable, just call reloadData on the second tableview and that should do the trick.]

Comment: I have called reloadData in viewDidLoad, also tried in cellForRow method.but didn't work.